# Forcing formulae stored in table linked to SQL database to evaluate

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in a spreadsheet linked to a SQL table elsewhere. There is a column which has a formula in it, akin to ="string1" & CHAR(10) & "string2". When linked, this column displays the formula instead of evaluating the formula. I can make it evaluate by replacing all the = signs with = signs, or pressing f2 on a cell and then enter, and repeating.

Is there a way to link a table and have the formulae stored in entries evaluate automatically? A table connection property I've overlooked? Pressing f9 doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the Power Query Add-In for this. It can start a Query from SQL data and add columns to each row using formulas. It can deliver the results into Excel Tables.